# Explanation for "Cannot access 'x' in 'y' in multi catch clause when build with Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I'm puzzled of the following compiler error "java.lang.Throwable.getMessage() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface" when I catch multiple exceptions, which inherit from same package protected abstract class.

The Maven build fails (Maven 3.8.x on Win/Mac/Unix ), compiling it with javac works.

But if I:

- only catch a single exception -> compiles
- catch  multiple exceptions (which inherit from same package protected abstract class) and add another exception (i.e. RuntimeException) -> compiles

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Main.java:

```
package com.foo.service;

import com.foo.utils.ExceptionA;
import com.foo.utils.ExceptionB;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException("RuntimeException");
      }
      if(true) {
        throw new ExceptionA("ExceptionA");
      }
      if (true) {
        throw new ExceptionB("ExceptionA");
      }
    } 
     catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB e) { // <- won't compile: "Cannot access 'getMessage()' in 'java.lang.Throwable'"
     e.getMessage();
    }
   //  catch (ExceptionA e) {  // <- compiles
   //  e.getMessage();
   // }
   //  catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB | RuntimeException e) { // <- compiles
    // e.getMessage();
    // }
  }
}
```

AbstractException.java:

```
package com.foo.utils;

class AbstractException extends Exception {
  protected AbstractException(final String message){
    super(message);
  }
}
```

ExceptionA.java:

```
package com.foo.utils;

public class ExceptionA extends AbstractException {
  public ExceptionA(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

ExceptionB.java:

```
package com.foo.utils;

public class ExceptionB extends AbstractException {
  public ExceptionB(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact reason is ... but If you don't care which exception occurred, you could just use `catch ( Exception e )`, but if you want to know exactly which, then use multiple catches, `catch ( ExceptionA a ) { ... } catch ( ExceptionB b ) { ... }`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I copy all your code and comment out the catch you claim won't compile, then it works for me without any problem. Only get a warning about "dead code" because of the if(true) blocks.

Comment: Did you maybe extend the wrong `Exception` class and not `java.lang.Exception` in `AbstractException`?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I even opened a new project for this.
Eclipse Adoptium jdk-11.0.16.8-hotspot on a Win 10 machine.

Comment: @matt: Thanks for taking time for this. I edited my question. I also gave this example to a colleague witch has a Mac. Same compiler error: ``java.lang.Throwable.getMessage() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface``. Are you sure you have the same package structure as in this example?

Comment: When this is build via Maven on a Win/Mac/Unix system, we get : ``.../src/main/java/com/foo/service/Main.java:[22,08] java.lang.Throwable.getMessage() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface``. I'll try to build it via javac.

Comment: Compiling with javac works. Thanks matt. Now I'll have to figure out what is causing this behavior in Maven. Does not make sense to me.

Comment: Yepp, only the 4.java Files + pom.xml don't work (testet on Win/Mac/Unix Ubuntu)

Comment: Related bugs: [JDK-8289980](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8289980), [JDK-8289975](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8289975)

Comment: Explains it. Can you please provide this as the answer.

Comment: The bug, which you've stumbled across is due to the fact that the LUB, AbstractException, is not accessible. It's a bit insane that it works with javac but fails with maven. Can you just make AbstractException public?

Comment: Yes, I made the AbstractException public, no big deal. My question initially was more about that I didn't understand the problem which I was facing. Thanks all for helping me out.